# Laravel query in if cause

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I run the below query, if cause true then where cause is apply like below, but when i run below query it gives me "Out of memory (allocated 503316480) (tried to allocate 492834816 bytes)" error, So another easy way to check the where cause above if condition.

Here below is my code.

```
$user_id = "";
$doctor_id = "";
$start_date = "";
$end_date = "";

if(isset($request->user_id)) {
    $user_id = $request->user_id;
}
if(isset($request->doctor_id)) {
    $doctor_id = $request->doctor_id;   
}
if(isset($request->start_date)) {
    $start_date = $request->start_date; 
}
if(isset($request->end_date)) {
    $end_date = $request->end_date; 
}

$query = DB::table('request_approves')
            ->join('city_masters', 'request_approves.city_id', '=', 'city_masters.id')
            ->join('doctors', 'request_approves.doctor_id', '=', 'doctors.id')
            ->select('doctors.*','city_masters.*','request_approves.*');

            if($user_id !== "") {
                $query->where('request_approves.user_id', 2);                        
            }

            if($doctor_id !== "") {
                $query->where('request_approves.doctor_id',3);    
            }

            if($start_date !== "" & $end_date !==""){
                $query->whereBetween('request_approves.approve_time', array($start_date,$end_date));    
            }
            $query->get();
```

Comment: There's a typo: `&` → `&&`

Comment: Try this to find the problem: Start with a basic query (`DB::table()`) and then add all the other parts (`->join()`, `->where()`) one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what it is happening, but your code seems wrong to me .
On the `if` statements you do something like this `$query->where('request_approves.user_id', 2);` but where this returned values go ? To continue the same query you should do it like this:

```
$query = DB::table('request_approves')
        ->join('city_masters', 'request_approves.city_id', '=', 'city_masters.id')
        ->join('doctors', 'request_approves.doctor_id', '=', 'doctors.id')
        ->select('doctors.*','city_masters.*','request_approves.*');

        if($user_id !== "") {
            $query = $query->where('request_approves.user_id', 2);                        
        }

        if($doctor_id !== "") {
            $query = $query->where('request_approves.doctor_id',3);    
        }

        if($start_date !== "" & $end_date !==""){
            $query = $query->whereBetween('request_approves.approve_time', array($start_date,$end_date));    
        }
        $query = $query->get();
```

Comment: Yes, Problem in the print query result, i was print the "$query->get()" this line two time so my memory allocation increases , now it's working. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses memory to perform queries as well. So performing queries from a PHP application will indeed use more memory than performing them straight from MySQL.

I did a simple calculation and 503316480 bytes comes out to 503MB. So I would suggest modifying your php.ini settings. This should let you output data, and from there you can tune your SQL.

In your php.ini

```
memory_limit=503M
```